# Having production and beta APK on the same device

Tags: android, google-play, publish

Can I have both production and beta versions of my application available to the selected users?

The use case is the following, there are some users that are willing to try new versions of my app, but the are already using stable version for work. Beta version may have bug/crashes, making it inadvisable for work use. Therefore it would be nice to have **both versions** installed.

If beta APK is published separately (e.g. on my website), the user has anyway to remove the stable APK.
If beta APK has different package name, I have to fork the repository, and then manage merge, which I what to avoid.

- Is there a standard way to do that on Play Store?
- Can user select which version to install from Play Store?
- Is there some tool that may simplify the package renaming?

Comment: If the package name is same then it's not possible.

Comment: [Check this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

Comment: @MD That's a weird answer, cause I need to upload an APK with the same package name to Production, Beta and Alpha as well. This is pretty logical considering you can transfer your APK from Alpha to Beta to Production. But I would also like to install an Alpha, Beta and Production on the same device at the same time.